# How to not compile certain code in goog.closure ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS

Tags: javascript, compilation, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

When I am using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS in closure, I can add to the `web.config` attributes such:

```
<compilation debug="false">
```

and than when I will write in my code:

```
if (goog.DEBUG) { code }
```

on advanced mode I will NOT see this script inside the .js file.

I would like to do the same with my own properties - I've created a define.js file:

Define.js:

```
goog.scope(function() {
    define.IS_SHOW_CODE = false;
}
```

and wrote code:
    if (!define.IS_SHOW_CODE) { code }

and I still CAN find this if and its content inside the compiled .js file!

How to prevent the closure from compiling script in advanced mode?

Comment: If you want to modify the value of a constant from the command line of the Closure Compiler (or whatever tool is calling the compiler) it needs to be annotated with @define. See https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Comments#Comments for examples.

Answer (score 1):

If "goog" works, likely you are missing the declaration of "define".

It should look something like this:

```
var define = {};  // goog.provide('define') would also work here.

/** @define {boolean} */
define.IS_SHOW_CODE = true;
```

Comment: explanation: `@define` makes a _compile-time_ constant, i.e. closure knows the value of this variable from the start and enforces it can't change.  so if it sees `if (define.IS_SHOW_CODE) { ... }` and knows the value must be `false`, it knows it can eliminate the entire block.

Comment: I think you are missing my point.  I'm saying an @define declared on an external namespace won't work as expected.  If the "define" namespace isn't declared, it will be assumed to be external and not inlined but the value is replaced at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found how -
i MUST use the prefix goog.[xxx]  in order to tell the compiler to remove the script inside.
using "define" instead didnt remove the script.

so i've changed the define.IS_SHOW_CODE  to goog.IS_SHOW_CODE

Comment: goog.* is intended to be used only for code that is part of Closure. The compiler's dead code elimination should work the same for goog.* or define.* or whatever.